# Is *HaMakom Yenachem* said Friday night in synagogue when the body's not yet buried?

Tags: mourning-aveilus, leil-shabbat

If there are *mourners* in shul Friday night, they are greeting with *HaMakom Yenachem Eschem* etc.

What if a relative died on Friday afternoon, but there's not enough time to bury before shabbos -- technically the family are in *Aninus* (preoccupation with burial), not *Aveilus*. Is it still said?

Comment: ואל תנחמנו בשעה שמתו מוטל לפניו

Comment: Note this line is said on Friday afternoon before Friday night (at the pre-Shabbat warm-up service "Kabbalat Shabbat"). Mourners aren't traditionally singled out on Shabbat, and even when incidentally comforting on Shabbat the traditional weekday-formulation isn't used ([OC 287](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%96_%D7%90))

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the time to really research this right now, but maybe this will trigger someone else's memory: IIRC, I learned once the reason we don't do this (not just Hamakom in Shul Friday night, but in general before the burial) is that it is the actual act of burial that itself provides some Nechama, so that only after that is done do we actually say "Hamakom Yenachem".

Comment: `What if a relative died on Friday afternoon, but there's not enough time to bury before shabbos` The family members do not even observe *aninus* yet in this scenario (*Kitzur Sh"A* 196:12, [*Yad Eliyahu* 16](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15100&st=&pgnum=53), comparing this to מת בתפיסה in *Sh"A* YD 341:4, though there's some discussion in other sources re. whether *aninus* applies to them for *d'varim sheb'tzin'a*). However, *Pischei T'shuva* (YD 341:22, based on *Noda' Biyhuda* YD 2:211) says if there's still enough time before Shabbos to prepare shrouds, *aninus* takes effect.